# Tic-Tac-Toe how do i call a 2d array in a function?

Tags: c++

So i'm making a tic tac toe game and i ran into a problem, what works atm:

- The board
- Input into board
- Board updates upon user input

What doesn't work:

- Win detection, (basically i have a function which is supposed to take board 2d array and then find out if the game has ended or not and that doesn't work for me)
- How would i call this function
- Are there any improvements to the code i currently have?

  ```
  bool GameState(char a[3][3], bool gameOver)
  ```

Github: https://github.com/MrCappucino/Tic-Tac-Toe/blob/master/main.cpp

EDIT: the function works fine now, code updated, but now it won't register winning states

EDIT 2: The win detection works, BUT now it only detects it 1 turn after it should be registering, kinda hard to explain so i'll give an example: x's are filled in 1, 5 and 9 (making a diagonal line from top-left to bottom-right) and registers the win only 1 turn later after o moves.

Comment: This is probably best answered by CodeReview@StackExchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all your cases, you didn't **update** the **value** of variable `gameOver`.

Instead of

```
GameState(board, gameOver);
```

Change it to

```
gameOver = GameState(board, gameOver);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but you still don't understand, i know how this works, but it just DOESN'T work, know what i mean? Look at my code, i call the function after every switch and it still doesn't register as a win :/

Comment: Then you shouldn't be asking how to implement the function. You should just post your code. It is your code logic having problems. How do you expect people to help improving your code when you only provided a function header?

Comment: First i was having problems with implementing the function, then i fixed that, now i'm having problems making it work.

Comment: @TheDude Just as I suspected, you didn't update your flag.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to write out all the cases

```
if(a[0][0] == 'X' && a[0][1]=='X' && a[0][2] == 'X') //across top row
{
   //won
}
else if(a[1][0] == 'X' && a[1][1]=='X' && a[1][2] == 'X') //across middle row
{
   //won
}   
//etc...
```

Comment: That wasn't my question, my question was how to implement this into a function.

Comment: I would do this and call the GameState function after every move

Comment: I fixed everything, win detection now works, BUT it only registers the win 1 move later, say i have x's in grid numbers 1 2 and 3 and then it only registers when o makes a move.